# Is it possible to debug ASP.NET Core assembly?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, debugging

I created a web api with ASP.NET Core and added Jwt Bearer Authentication. I want to know how the framework authenticate the token but I can't add breakpoints to the handling code because the framework is compiled to assembly. I have the downloaded code of ASP.NET Core framework (from GitHub) and my app source code, so how can I debug to know how the framework works?

Answer (score 1):

To step into the framework source code, you should configure VS Code or VS accordingly,

- [Steps for VS Code](https://halfblood.pro/how-to-step-into-net-core-source-code-in-vs-code/)
- [Steps for VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/debug-aspnetcore-source?view=aspnetcore-7.0)